# Rows do not match Subscriber and Publisher

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, c#

I have an transactional replication setup with updateable subscription that is utilized by an Application. When I insert a project into the application, the msrepl_tran_version is different on the publisher and the subscriber. Hence, when I go to perform the update it does not update as the rows do not match.

[image: Right is the publisher and left is the subscriber]

Is this happening due to a trigger?
How can I resolve this issue. As mentioned it only happens when I update certain combobox from the application which is 3 columns from this table.

How can I fix this issue.!!! Even when I run the distribution agent, it will fix it but then when the user performs a new insert the problem occurs again.

I know this is similar to [my other post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46465/does-existing-msrepl-tran-version-column-need-to-be-removed-when-re-creating-rep) but this provides more details.

Comment: Which other post? If this is clarification of the same problem, please edit the other question instead of reposting.